# “Ailleurs” in this sentence

Tags: sens, indications-de-lieu

In this [text](http://www.aleteia.org/fr/religion/article/quelle-est-lorigine-du-mercredi-des-cendres-5799235291185152), on the first paragraph after "Confesser ses fautes", we read:

> Ailleurs, les pénitents publics accomplissaient leur peine en privé, autrement dit chez eux.

I'm having a bit of trouble to understand what "Ailleurs" means in this context. Could I translate it as 'otherwise' here? In this [site](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/ailleurs/) that meaning is not present, but with those that are, the text doesn't seem to make sense…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me the simplest translation would be: "Elsewhere".
 "Otherwise"  is translated to "Autrement".

In the text, the previous sentence begins with “Dans la Rome du VIe siècle, …”. So here *ailleurs* refers to places other than Rome.